# Seemingly Impossible Maze

Tags: lateral-thinking

I assure you it's completely possible.

I made this maze myself so no copyright stuff :D

Rules:

- You start at the bottom right corner.
- You end at the top left corner.
- No going around the maze, over the maze, or under the maze.
- No walking through walls.
- No teleportation.

Maze:

[image: Maze]

Good luck!

Comment: Never said anything about movement along 4th dimension http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-dimensional_space

Comment: No walking through walls?  What walls?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you look at it carefully enough, it's the easiest maze ever.

> Normally, when one does a maze, one goes between the lines.
>  You didn't specify this as a rule. If you begin on the black line in the lower right hand corner, and follow it, unbroken, to the upper left... it's a breeze.

Comment: Good job! I can accept in 5 min.

Comment: Would you like to include an image in your answer?

Comment: I would, once I get time to draw one. :D

Comment: Don't forget to add one!

Comment: Oh, and @warspyking notify me when you do!

Comment: "no walking through walls"... no means no. Walking along and inside is still through.

Comment: It should say "No crossing from one side of the wall to the other"

Comment: @Mazura only if the black represents the wall. If the white represents the wall, then it's compliant with the rules (though it would work better if the break between lines on the top left were on the left wall instead of the top wall)

Comment: The white cannot represent the wall, because the path starts "in the bottom right corner", which is white.

Comment: @Sneftel I don't know what you're talking about; the pixels in the lowest and furthest right part of the maze are dark grey.

Comment: @anorton Good point. Making the maze even more impossible.

Answer (score 24):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for...

> This picture actually has a white border (roughly 8px wide), with the edges defined by four points.  Assuming this is part of the maze, simply follow either the left or upward paths, following one of these paths until the destination is reached.

Comment: That's what I was thinking!

Comment: Yep, this seems like a better answer, especially because [gurer ner yvggyr znexf ba gur pbearef bs gur vzntr, cerfhznoyl gb tvir lbh n uvag](http://www.rot13.com).

Comment: I don't think this was the intent, but +1 anyway because the image was done poorly and this was my first thought upon seeing it (I had to open in a new window and scale it down to fit the screen) too.

Comment: @WChargin for a moment I thought that was German!

Comment: However, there's a rule specifically stating "No going around the maze" so this interpretation nevertheless seems less likely.

Comment: @nitro2k01 The confines of the maze were never stated, it's a fair assumption to assume that the image extents are the edges of the maze.

Answer (score 23):

I entered the maze, intrigued by the difficulty caused by the fact that the exit was blocked off by a wall. Attached to my belt, I had one less powerful grenade and two more powerful grenades. I was glad to find out that the walls were made of a less sturdy material, meaning that a grenade could easily knock down the wall. I tested the weak grenade on an unnecessary wall, and to my delight, it worked! I proceeded by using a larger grenade on the wall that was blocking the exit. Not to my delight, there was a police officer guarding the exit! I used my last grenade and ran towards the exit. I made it out of the maze successfully.

[image]

Comment: Crop the time part out of your image, and +1 lol.

Comment: This is not a good answer.  This should be downvoted.

Comment: @thinlyveiledquestionmark Lateral thinking tends to be the flag that says "Everything is right."

Comment: @Xrylite Questions that involve lateral thinking that don't produce an answer which is demonstrably and definitively correct are off-topic. That being said, I don't think "creative" answers help the problem, either.

Comment: "well a dinosaur mysteriously popped out of a time machine, rampaged through 4 of the maze's wall, allowing our hero to make his way from point a to point b" yeah, that isn't going to cut it

Comment: The good old Castle Wolfenstein technique (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castle_Wolfenstein)

Comment: @thinlyveiledquestionmark / Emrakul you guys are no fun. xD

Comment: Would have been ok had the time on the clock roughly matched the one on the screenshot :)

Comment: @nich He does just my image. I used Touch Lua draw library to make the maze (Touch Lua is free, draw library isn't.)

Comment: Yes I know I'm weird using a programming app to make a maze XD

Comment: and moreover you could have skipped 2nd step :P ;)

Comment: Am I the only one who thought this could be made better with an 8-bit sprite of Link and his bombs?

Answer (score 20):

The rules can be satisfied without even entering the maze.

> There's "No going around the maze", but nothing to say "The maze can't go around". So if you stand at the bottom-right corner of the maze, and rotate it 180 degress about its centre, you will end up at the top-left corner of the maze.

Comment: That truly is lateral thinking.

Answer (score 1):

Place your dot onto he bottom right corner... fold the paper so the bottom right corner touches the top left corner.  Its that easy